# documentGetElementById() is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending pdf file to server, and the form for creation of pdf file is not rendered, when the page loads. Its rendered when user click on something... 
The problem is, that I cannot select id "file" which is input type="file" (html is generated by javascript). 
How to select it the same as I am doing it with this code (the same result).
Thank you

```
$('.content').on('click','.file-btn', function() {

  var data = new FormData();
  var input = document.getElementById('file');

  const title = $("#title").val();
  const description = $("#textarea").val();
  const sharingWith = $("#dropdown").val();


  data.append('file', input.files[0]);

  console.log("file" + data.get("file"));
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: 'https://localhost:8443/documents'+ "?title="+title + "&desc="+description + "&Role="+sharingWith ,
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.access_token},
      success: function (data) {
          alert("works!");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
      }
  });
  })


export const createDocumentForm = () => {
    const markup = `<form class="doc_form" id="doc-form">
    <label for="title" id="title-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" required placeholder="Title">
    <label for="textarea" id="textarea-label">Description</label>
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter description" required  rows="5"></textarea>
    <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown-label">Select groups for sharing document</label>
    <select name="select" id="dropdown" multiple required>
      <option value="USER">USER</option>
      <option value="SUPERIOR">SUPERIOR</option>
      <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    </select>
    <div class="doc_sender">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="id_form">
          <input type="file" id="file"/>
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-doc file-btn">Save file!</button>
  </div>
  </form>`;

    elements.content.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
};
```

Comment: How do you generate the HTML? Does it assign an I'd to the input type file

Comment: If `document.getElementById('file')` returns null, you can be 100% sure that that means there is no element on the page with that id. Use your developer tools to inspect the element that you *think* has that id and see what's going on.

Comment: Wrap your jQuery code with `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: @Pointy That input with id is rendered OK with that id... strange is, that the same happens for other elements like "title" (also generated by js), but when I used jquery $("#title).val() - it was selected ok... but I dont know, how to select that input field to give me the same result as In the code above...

Comment: @Ram Segev did not help :(

Comment: What matters is the state of the DOM at the moment the code attempts to find it. Again, your browser is not broken: if it says there's no element with that id, then there is no element with that id *at the time the function was called*.

Answer (score 0):

try using this to get your file

```
var input = $("#file").get(0).files[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

1st: be sure your html file you have the main.js is below the src of jQuery src

2nd: wrap your js code like the example below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('your document is ready ...');
  // your code ....

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```